# Spring AOP Aspect used in JdbcOperations not invoked

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-jdbc

**I want to do something like this**: http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/java-programming/log-sql-statements-with-parameter-values-filled-in-spring-jdbc/

I have a Spring MVC project and I'm using Spring 4.3.0.RELEASE.

I'm using a Generic Abstract Class for all my DAOS

```
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl {
    @Autowired
    protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
}


@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl extends GenericDaoImpl implements UserDAO{

}
```

*jdbcTemplate* is defined in my auto-config.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

**In order to implement something closer to whats in that guide I have**:

Added these dependencies to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
```

I've added *@EnableAspectJAutoProxy* to the *@Configuration* Class.

And my Aspect is:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SqlParametersLogger {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SqlParametersLogger.class);

    @Before("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations.*(..))")
    public void log(JoinPoint jp) {
        logger.info("Hello?");
    }
}
```

My Aspect function is never called. I've tried this Aspect with pointcuts of my Service layers, and it works. But with JdbcOperations it does not work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Your aop expression is defined as a pointcut to a JdbcOperation.* which is an interface, and interface calls are not advised.

AspectJ can intercept pointcuts in the spring framework for spring-managed-beans. 
If the bean is not spring managed you'll need to manually register it using ProxyFactoryBean/ProxyFactory for advisal. In your case you already have a bean implementing the JdbcOperations interface registered in your spring application-context.

As per your problem changing the pointcut to use any implementation of the JdbcOperations interface ( the `jdbcTemplate` bean definition )  should solve your problem.

For example

```
@Before("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations+.*(..))")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Alex. I've changed 

`@Before("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations.*
(..))")`

to 

`@Before("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations+.*(..))")` but still no invocation of the Aspect.

Comment: I even tried to set it directly to `@Before("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.*(..))")` but also no invocation of the Aspect

Answer (score 0):

you lost 1 `.*` in the expression,it should be

```
// this works fine 
@Before("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core..*JdbcOperations.*(String, ..))")
```

But you wrote like

```
// this's not good 
@Before("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations.*(..))")
```

This answer came to me unexpectedly when I saw this ,link here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58282255/how-to-intercept-jdbctemplate-whose-instance-is-created-by-myself`