# How to intercept JdbcTemplate whose instance is created by myself

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, jdbctemplate

What I want do is collect DB statistical values after any **DQL** ("SELECT ...") or **DML** (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE ...) which is performed for current session.
Current, I have leveraged **Spring AOP** to achieve this as follows:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class StatisticalValueCollector {
    @After("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core..*JdbcOperations.*(String, ..))")
    public void collectStatisTicalValues(JoinPoint jp) {
        //Collect DB statistical values
    }
 }
```

It works perfectlly for both `JdbcTemplate` and `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` annotated by `@Autowired`, but when I create their instanceㄋ by myself, it doesn't work.

**Worked example:**

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
...
List<Map<String, Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT ...");
```

**Not worked example:**

```
DriverManagerDatasource ds = new DriverManagerDatasource();
...
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate (ds);
List<Map<String, Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT ...");
```

As far as I know, it seems that the if the `JdbcTemplate` is created by Spring, it can be proxyed according to this post - [AOP: Able to Intercept JDBCTemplate calls but not NamedParameterJdbcTemplate calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52634043/aop-able-to-intercept-jdbctemplate-calls-but-not-namedparameterjdbctemplate-cal)
.

Therefore, my question is "**How to intercept `JdbcTemplate` or `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` created by myself?**";
Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I also surveyed different approaches like [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) and [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy), it seems the only solution is to use pure **AspectJ** or something else?

Comment: Hello. You asked a question, I answered it. So please check my answer, then accept + upvote if you think it is correct (I certainly do).

Answer (score 1):

If in both cases you print your JDBC template instance like this

```java
System.out.println(jdbcTemplate + "\n  " + jdbcTemplate.getClass());
```

then for the one you created by yourself you will see

```
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@3c71cf3e
  class org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
```

while for the auto-injected one you will see

```
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@8f39224
  class org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$59a5407f
```

Spot the difference? For the latter Spring creates a dynamic proxy if an aspect targeting it exists. Only if there is a dynamic proxy, Spring AOP has something to register its aspect advices on.

I am not a Spring user, so I don't know if there is another canonical way create JDBC templates for which automatically a dynamic proxy is created on demand. So unless you want to manually create a proxy (which is possible but unnecessarily complicated) or find another way to do so, just use dependency injection (DI) and auto-wiring. Was that not that the whole point of using Spring in the first place? Creating dependencies you can get injected is kind of an anti-pattern for a DI container like Spring.

If you insist on your unorthodox and hard to test (how to inject a mock for a local variable you call a constructor on?) approach, you can always use full AspectJ as an alternative to Spring AOP. But I doubt it is worth it in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I knew that I cannot proxy the object which is created by Spring with Spring AOP. So I will take your suggestion into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

In a class annotated with `@Configuration`, define your `JdbcTemplate` as a `@Bean`:

```
@Configuration
public class JdbcConfiguration {

    private DriverManagerDatasource ds = new DriverManagerDatasource();

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }
}
```

This way, you enable Spring to proxy it with AOP when intercepting it in an `@Aspect`, by putting your `JdbcTemplate` bean into `ApplicationContext`. You can now autowire it with:

```
@Autowired private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Comment: Yeah, of course, but the question was how to use AOP in connection with JDBC templates which are **not** auto-wired.

Comment: You cannot use AOP with an instance you create with `new`. I just gave you a way to intercept _your_ `JdbcTemplate`'s methods by making it a Spring managed `@Bean`.

Comment: @kriagaex, you might have posted it under the wrong answer.